# Adding a character in Notepad++ in a specific position, but only to lines beginning with a specific character... Also then need a space removed

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file. Every other line begins with "C". I need a dash added to the specific position, but also then need to remove a space at the end of that specific data element where the dash was added. I know I can use Find: ^(.{7}) and Replace with: $1- and that will add my dash on every line, but now I need help getting it to only do it to lines beginning with a "C", and removing the space, as below. This is editing a fixed-width file and is the reason for the space removal being needed. Thanks in advance!

Example Line

```
C1234567     TEST
```

I would need a dash at pos 7, but then need one of the five spaces at the end of C1234567 removed

Resulting Line

```
C12345-67    TEST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^C.{5})(..)`   # notice the space at the end
- Replace with: `$1-$2`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(           # group 1
    C.{5}       # C followed by 5 any character
)           # end group 1
(..)        # group 2, 2 any character
            # a space
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Toto, worked perfectly!

Comment: @TravisElijah: You're welcome, glad it helps.